# Executing a program with various parameters (loop)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a program, `prog`, which takes an integer argument when I call it from the terminal, eg:

```
./prog 10
```

I would like to execute `prog` with a range of values, e.g. `10, 20, 30, ...`. Is there a neat way to do it, besides using:

```
./prog 10 ; ./prog 20 ; ./prog 30 ; ....
```

Comment: you do `for i in 10 20 30 ...; do ./prog $i; done`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop with Bash, Zsh or Ksh93.
The following works only since Bash version 4 (2009), zsh 4.3.10 (2010) and ksh93r (2006) (though the `{x..y}` syntax originated in `zsh` (in `2.6-beta4` in 1995)).

```
#!/bin/bash
# since Bash v4
for i in {10..100..10}
do
     $path_of_prog/prog $i
done
```

The `{$start..$end..$step}` part says that `$i` is at the start equal to `$start` and `$i` will go to `$end`.
The `$step` is the amount with which `$i` will be increased each step.
So we get the values `10 20 30 ... 100` for `$i`.

You could also write it all in one line with

```
for i in {10..100..10}; do ./prog $i; done
```

If you have an older Bash and GNU `seq` is available, use the following lines

```
#!/bin/bash
#only for pre Bash v4
for i in $(seq 10 10 100)
do
   $path_of_prog/prog $i
done
```

or as a one liner

```
for i in $(seq 10 10 100);do ./prog $i; done
```

(the above assumes you've not modified the `$IFS` variable).

Answer (score 6):

The question is tagged `bash`, this is just for the benefit of users of other shells.

In a POSIX sh script (for portability):

```
i=10
while [ "$i" -le 100 ]; do
  ./prog "$i"
  i=$(($i+10))
done
```

In a Bourne sh script (for compatibility to pre-90s systems):

```
echo '0[10+pd100>x]dsxx' | dc | xargs -n 1 ./prog
```

In `zsh` (for people not constrained to use `bash`):

```
i=0; repeat 10 ./prog $((i+=10))
```

Or

```
for i ({1..10}0) ./prog $i
```

or:

```
for ((i=10;i<=100;i+=10)) ./prog $i
```

or:

```
zargs -n1 {1..10}0 -- ./prog
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can get printf to do this for you, but here are just a couple:

```
printf ' ./prog %d0\n' 1 2 3 | sh
```

Or maybe you want the program to actually run 30 times. *`seq`uence* and *`printf`* are pretty well matched to this end:

```
printf ' ./prog %d\n'  `seq 1 30` | sh
```

Or maybe the results of your command involve some variable value that you don't want to sacrifice on the the far side of a pipe. Ok.:

```
. <<CMD /dev/fd/0
    $(printf './prog %d0\n' 1 2 3 )
CMD
```

Possibly you dont want the numbers but you want so many copies of a string, or maybe only part of the command needs repeating but other parts are static:

```
 . <<CMD /dev/fd/0
    $( { printf 'echo "this is part 1" >&2| ' ;\
    printf 'echo "these are parts %d" >&2 | ' `seq 1 5` ; })
CMD

printf 'this string is repeated for each of printfs args, 
    but the args are not included%.0b\n' `seq 1 5`
```